# HttpError 403 with CONSUMER_INVALID as the reason when deploying a machine learning model to Google cloud's AI platform

Tags: google-api-client, google-api-python-client, google-ai-platform

I am following the tutorial here (https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/training-jobs#python_1) and using Python to deploy a machine learning model to Google cloud for training. However, I got HttpError 403: "Permission denied on resource project my_project." The reason for the error is "CONSUMER_INVALID." Specifically, the returned metadata shows that the consumer is "projects/my_project," and the service is "ml.googleapis.com".

I went to the AI platform and my project is indeed there. The API I am requesting to use is enabled for the project and the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS has been set correctly. I am wondering how to fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I ran into this issue when I used my literal Project Name. I had to instead use the 'ProjectID' which is listed in the 'Home' Dashboard, in the 'Project info' widget.

Comment: This helped me, Google has wrong instructions. Following your comment I just replaced the 'project id' and used the 'project number' instead and now it works. Thank you

Comment: Thanks! I found that that when using gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project  we need to use the ProjectID from the Home dashboard but I was still stuck at this since I still had to update the ProjectID on my code.

Comment: In my case, I had a whitespace included on the env variable holding the project ID. Check for typos!

Answer (score 1):

So If you want to acces the secret over the `project ID` not `project NR` you will need to attach `Service Usage Viewer` role to your SA. Then you can use the projectId as expected.