# Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'recaptchaenterprise.assessments.create' denied on resource

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha

I keep getting this error, I am trying to implement google reCaptcha v3, I gave myself all possible permissions on my service account but nothing seems to work.
I don't even understand the error.

these are some lines of the error from the terminal.

> Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'recaptchaenterprise.assessments.create' denied on resource '//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/my-project-auth-330511' (or it may not exist)

> ...\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:31
> return Object.assign(new Error(message), status);

```
statusDetails: [
    ErrorInfo {
      metadata: {
        permission: 'recaptchaenterprise.assessments.create',
        resource: 'projects/my-project-auth-330511'
      },
      reason: 'IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED',
      domain: 'cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com'
    }
  ],
  reason: 'IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED',
  domain: 'cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com',
```

I would like to know what causes this error.

Comment: The following answer worked for me:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/70072816/1594274](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70072816/1594274)

Answer (score 9):

You should create a service account at [credentials page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials).

Then, give `reCaptcha Enterprise Agent` role on creation (we did not manage to add roles to existing service-account).

- [Create service account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDczY.png)
- [Give it some name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQpQy.png)
- [Assign recaptcha agent role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkQtf.png)